# multiple parameter selection in crystal report in .net not working

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Form contains 1 texbox to hold Student ID and two Date-time Picker to select fees paid month by student and i am able to select date range of all students , where unable to filter fromdate to Todate with particular one Student.

i am getting error ....Please Help....... here is my problem code

```
Dim dbCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim myreport As New CrystalReport2
Dim Dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

dbCommand.CommandText = "Select  FeesMonth between #" & FromDate.Text & "#  and #" & ToDate.Text & "# From StudentPayments Where StudentID= '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        da.SelectCommand = dbCommand
        da.Fill(Dt)
        myreport.SetDataSource(Dt)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport
        CrystalReportViewer1.Show
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give Connectionstring to dbCommand.

like -

OleDbConnection  con=new OleDbConnection ();

**dbCommand.Connectionstring=con;**

Comment: thanks for replay, form loading event itself has a open connection string

Comment: but you have not mentioned in your code. also check connection is opened or not check it.

Comment: thanku sir, it has a open coonection and there is no data connection error and printpreview button will display the empty sheet